# Composer on Ubuntu 16.04 trough apt or trough php -r. Is there any difference?

Tags: php, composer-php

I am running  a Ubuntu 16.04 and want to install Composer.
I have 2 options at least:

1. Through [Composer.org site recommendations](https://getcomposer.org/download/) command line-> `php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');" ...`
2. Trough apt -> `atp install composer`, as you can see below:
   [image]
   So, is there any constraint to install trough process 2?

Answer (score 1):

If you install through the package manager, you're going to get an older version. Whether or not that matters is up to you. There are benefits to installing everything through the package manager; namely, it becomes easy to keep your entire system up-to-date (by Ubuntu's definition of up-to-date). There are also obvious benefits to following a given piece of software's instructions.

Personally, if I were sharing code with other developers who use composer, I'd install composer through the 'recommended' way and try to keep it up to date by checking periodically for new versions on the website. That way we'd all be using the same version.